# Avoiding detached head when working together

Tags: github, detach

for my course I have to code something together with my partner. In order to be able to work together on a code project we thought GitHub may be the perfect because of the revisions and possibility to work on a single file simultaneously(at least we think that this is possible).

We use Github for all the git stuff and when one of us codes something, he first makes sure that the repo says "in sync", then commits his stuff and syncs again.
BUT it happens from time to time that one of us(or both of us then) get the DETACHED HEAD problem. Both of us don't understand what we are doing wrong. We are working on a single branch(master) so there should not be any "branch problems" or something like that, I think.

So basically, I would like to know what we have to do to avoid such thing since we also lost some code when that happened some times. Or if we do wrong by working on a single file at the same time.

Example:

1. My partner committed something in "os_mem_drivers.c" and "os_memory_strategies.c".
2. I was working on "os_memory.c" and "os_memheap_drivers.c" and wanted to commit now.
3. So therefore I opened Github, wanted to commit and got a sync conflict (talking about git rebase etc)

Comment: Be careful with your partner, or one of you might end up with a detached head.

Comment: Seriously though, please describe what exactly you're doing so you're getting in this state.

Comment: More details please. Are you using a GUI (which one) or the command line? What exact command did you type, or what exactly did you click in the GUI? Also post the exact error message you got.

Comment: We use Github and the error message is:
There was a conflict while syncing. Open a shell to resolve and stage the conflicts, then continue the merge with "git rebase --continue". Or click "Abort Sync" to go back where you were before syncing.

Comment: GitHub is not a GUI, AFAIK it's just a git hosting service. What desktop client are you using?

Comment: Github is also the windows client (http://windows.github.com/).

Comment: Try using command-line git. See if you still have the problem when pulling, committing, and pushing from the command line.